# How to render Login form on Home page

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

How can I render the React bootstrap login form on the same home page instead of routing to fresh new `/login` page?

what i mean by that is, the moment i click on the `LogIn` link, the current page activities (page controls like click, scroll) should be disabled and just display the login form. how can i achieve that?

**what i have already done**

created react-bootstrap project and added the simple login form using [link](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/)

below is the code in **App.js**

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} /> 
        <Route path="/login" component={Login1} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer isn't as concise as it could be.

I believe you want to have one Home page and a "Log In" link will be within that home page.

When the log in link is clicked the other elements on the page "disappear" and the login form will be displayed on that same page.

If the above statement is true then, you need to put a "Log In" link within the Home component to start.

There are many ways to tackle this, the quickest way would be to use state.

In the constructor of a class component initialise state as follows:

```
constructor(props)
{
  super(props);
  
  this.state = {
   toggleLogin: false
  }
}
```

Now in the render function you want to use conditional rendering:

```
render(){
  
  var contentToRender = this.state.toggleLogin ? <form>I'm a log in form</form> : <p> I'm a paragraph 
  </p>

  return ({ contentToRender })
}
```

Finally you will need a function to alter state when your log in link is clicked.

```
loginClicked = () => {

  this.setState({ toggleLogin: true })
}
```

When the login link triggers the "loginClicked" function, state will be altered, causing a re-render which will see that the "toggleLogin" field within the state object is now true and therefore rendering the form tag and not the paragraph tag.

If you feel I have not been clear enough, I can clarify.

Comment: Thanks. you understood my question.  I know you have provided sample code above, but can you also point me to the more detailed sample code where i can do some POC ? Thanks